# AWS deployment failed - jhipster app - EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster

I  have tried deploying my jhipster application in AWS Elastic BeanStalk by uploading the war directly. When the environment is created, i am getting this error.

```
 [Instance: i-08f7c9efd8b2c5476] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 
 Output: (TRUNCATED).../util/SystemPropertyUtils.class Failed to execute 
  '/usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging 
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle' Failed to execute 
  '/usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging 
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle'. Hook 
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/restartappserver/pre/01_configure_application.sh 
   failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Please suggest me what  to do next.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU5tL.png)

I have also tried using **yo jhipster:aws** command as per the documentation in the jhipster page.

What i am getting is **Missing credentails Config**  .

my question is i have added **credentials.properties** file in the given loaction
~/.aws/credentials...

Means .aws/credentials/credentials.properties (file).   is the file extension right and the folder structure right,.

```
  Create S3 bucket
  Error jhipster:aws

  Missing credentials in config
```

Comment: First, ElasticBeanstalk should be abbreviated as `EB`. Amazon uses `EBS` to mean Elastic Block Store. Also, can you please post the contents of `/var/log/eb-activity.log`? You can use `eb ssh` to log into your instance and retrieve the log, or `eb logs` from your development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your first error as you are trying to set the environment up manually and we would need information to reproduce.

In regards to `yo jhipster:aws` failing, the AWS credentials file should be located at `~/.aws/credentials`, not `~/.aws/credentials/credentials.properties`

> After that create a credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials on Mac/Linux or C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\credentials on Windows.

From the docs: https://jhipster.github.io/aws/

Answer (score 0):

For further clarification, use vi and create a file named "credentials" under the "~/.aws" folder.